# User Array.filter with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using array.filter to filter the following array

```
let array =   [[75, -5750, 115],
 [76, -5750, 115],
 [93, -5750, 115],
 [94, -5750, 115],
 [95, -5750, 115],
 [96, -5750, 115],
 [97, -5750, 115],
 [98, -5750, 115],
 [99, -5750, 115]]

var lucky = array.filter(a=>a[0]>75); //this works
console.log(lucky);
```

I want to achieve something like

```
var lucky = array.filter(a=>98>a[0]>75); //apply two condition //it returns whole array in this case
```

How to achieve this ???

Comment: You can't combine the test like this in javascript; it needs to be separate: `98 > a[0] && a[0] > 75`

Comment: yup thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you want is the [logical and operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). Something like this:

```
array.filter(a => 98 > a[0] && a[0] > 75);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `&&` to only return true if 2 conditions are met

```js
let array = [
  [75, -5750, 115],
  [76, -5750, 115],
  [93, -5750, 115],
  [94, -5750, 115],
  [95, -5750, 115],
  [96, -5750, 115],
  [97, -5750, 115],
  [98, -5750, 115],
  [99, -5750, 115]
]

var lucky = array.filter(a => a[0] > 75 && a[0] < 98);
console.log(lucky);
```

`.filter()` takes a function as an argument. In this case that would be the same as

```
function(element){
  return element[0] > 75 && element[0] < 98;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use logical operator to combine two conditions

When you want all the conditions to be must than you use `&` AND operator.

When you want consitons to be optional than you use `|` OR operator.

```js
let array =   [[75, -5750, 115],
 [76, -5750, 115],
 [93, -5750, 115],
 [94, -5750, 115],
 [95, -5750, 115],
 [96, -5750, 115],
 [97, -5750, 115],
 [98, -5750, 115],
 [99, -5750, 115]]

var lucky = array.filter(a=>a[0]>75 && a[0]<98); //this works
console.log(lucky);
```